# CSS Only Multiple onclick events

Tags: html, css

This is generally a hack which i am trying to figure out in css, From what I can gather it should be working in theory and it isn't.

```css
#expand {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

#btn {
  display: none;
}

#btn:checked+label:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#btn:checked+label:after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#btn:checked+.button:before {
  display: none;
}

#btn:checked+.button:after {
  display: inline-block;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button:before,
.button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  transition: transform 0.35s ease-out;
}


/* Vert Line */

.button:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 46%;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}


/* Horiz Line */

.button:after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.inform {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="expand">
  <input id="btn" type="checkbox">
  <label class="button" for="btn"></label>
  <div class="inform">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Alot of content.</p>
  </div>
```

So as you can see, I have the "hack" for the click event on changing the style for `.button` using a checkbox.
I then used the `+` selector to target the div `.inform`.
If i am correct the `+` selector means it targets the immediate following element, In which case this should work. But it does not, Could someone possibly help clear my understanding of this and if i am wrong, otherwise could you help point me in the right direction to get this to work.

Summary:
I would like to get the header and paragraph to display when the checkbox is checked, aswell as getting the + symbol to rotate.

Comment: What does not work ? Your "+" changes to "-" onclick and back. What do you want to get?

Comment: I will re-edit hold on

Comment: Down-voted and no comment as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got similar selectors:

```css
#btn:checked+.button:before {
  display: none;
}

#btn:checked+.button:before {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And `#btn:checked+label:before` and `#btn:checked+.button:before` are the same thing.

I think it should look like:

```css
#expand {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

#btn {
  display: none;
}

#btn:checked+label:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#btn:checked+label:after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#btn:checked+.button:before {
  display: none;
}

#btn:checked ~ .inform {
  opacity: 1;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button:before,
.button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  transition: transform 0.35s ease-out;
}


/* Vert Line */

.button:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 46%;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}


/* Horiz Line */

.button:after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.inform {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="expand">
  <input id="btn" type="checkbox">
  <label class="button" for="btn"></label>
  <div class="inform">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Alot of content.</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was after... With a slight tweak

Comment: I kept `.inform` the same with `display:none` and changed the `#btn:checked ~ .inform` to `display: inline-block`, It does the same thing i wanted but keeps the code minimal, I knew this would work...